# Are there regular car chassis that would fit a Lamborghini outer shell?

Tags: modification, lamborghini

I'm not quite sure if these shells are for replica/kit cars or movie stunt cars, maybe both: https://www.duraflex-racing.com/lamborghini-replicas

I found some chassis plans off eBay for the Lamborghini Murcielago. Although, what about just using the chassis... and well, *everything* besides the outer metal, windows and doors--to connect to the Lambo shell? I would think it would mostly just need to fit, and perhaps some additional structure emboldened (welded and bolted) into the frame for butterfly doors.

There has to be some regular cars that can fit this super car, and potentially be modified. Have any ideas? The main issue I see with most cars would be to modify the axles and transmission to a lower position, higher up in the chassis.

Comment: Why not call the company and ask? Porsche Boxters are common donor cars for this sort of kit car, but these replicas look more like film cars, and wouldn't pass safety.

Comment: I emailed them asking for resources two days ago.

Comment: I called them, and they just said to find stuff on facebook and youtube :/
That's not good enough.